# celery signals not being received from the celery batch processing

Tags: celery

I am using celery.contrib.batches to execute a batch of celery tasks. I know its experimental but still wanted to give it a try and I am pretty close. While executing individual tasks in the batch and I am sending signals like backend.mark_as_started(request.id), backend.mark_as_done(request.id, True) deliberately. But the signals are not being received at the worker. Note that everything works if I get rid of batches and execute task one a time. Meaning, my signal handler functions do get executed.

Answer (score 1):

The celery.contrib.Batches indeed do not send these signals. The solution is to send those signals from inside the Batch task.